# Get code from Silverlight publish?

Tags: silverlight, xap

Is there a way to get the code from a Silverlight publish?

My laptop has completely crashed, and the only thing I have left from my application, is the published website.

Is there a tool or something to get the code from my application?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can rename the xap to zip, extract it, and use Reflector to pull out the code. It won't recover it exactly or recover the XAML though. As far as I know there's no way to reverse engineer XAML.

Edit: +1 for Shawn for pointing out that the XAML is stored as plaintext resources, so you can recover that too. Not quite sure *why* it does that, but hey, it's good news :-)

Answer (score 4):

Using .NET Reflector you *can* can all the XAML. It's stored as resources in plain text.

Comment: where do you find those xaml-files??

Comment: Look at the Resource folder at the bottom of the assembly, and it will have the namespace it in.  I you click it you'll see the XAML.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Silverlight Spy](http://silverlightspy.com/silverlightspy/download-silverlight-spy/). It's a great tool for debugging Silverlight. If you use it in combination with [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) you can view the decompiled code of any running Silverlight application.

BTW, [here](http://firstfloorsoftware.com/silverlightspy/introduction/) are all features of Silverlight Spy.

Comment: how can i import my dll's or xap file in silverlight spy?

Comment: you can browse to the url where your app is running with silverlight spy, and it will find the xap file.

Comment: That's allready fixed, but where is the option to decompile my xap-file?

Comment: In the explorer panel you can look at the contents of a xap file. after you've selected a dll. goto the view tab on the view panel. You have to have reflector installed.

Answer (score 1):

JetBrains have made [DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) available. It is currently free (I hope it stays that way, unlike .NET Reflector).

It will also convert Silverlight DLL files all the way back to readable source code! I have tried it on several Silverlight projects, and it works like a charm.

**Note: as of the time of this writing it still gets a couple of things wrong: string concatenations and event handlers generate the wrong code.*